# facebook FQL query performance within foreach loop?

Tags: php, facebook, performance, foreach

I'm trying to request some information from facebook's FQL, but the request is a little slow.

```
$friend = "SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() LIMIT 30";

  $friendSQL = $facebook->fql($friend);
  foreach ($friendSQL as $friends_id){
    $uid2 = $friends_id['uid2']; 
     $query = "SELECT uid,username,name,pic_small FROM user WHERE uid='".$uid2."'";
     $friend_info = $facebook->fql($query);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($friend_info);
    echo "</pre>";
  }
```

So basically, I'm getting a list of 30 friends and I'm trying to use a foreach loop to get other information from `uid2` (which is my friend)

I've noticed that the request is slow. Is there another way of getting information of my friends?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your select statement could look something like:

```
SELECT uid,username,name,pic_small FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() LIMIT 30)
```

So you won't have to use the loop anymore. This is pretty much the same as FQL Multiquery.

Comment: Excellent!  I was just about to post this FQL too.

Answer (score 1):

Your script is slow because it makes new HTTP request in each iteration and every new request takes a lot of time. Correct way to do this is using [FQL.multiquery](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.multiquery/). With multiquery you can get all info you want in one HTTP request without using foreach.